# Empty select box with Ionic Angular ng-option

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am facing an issue with Angular and Ionic. I have the following snippet:

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('CatagoryItemsContoller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  'use strict';

  $scope.stringArr = ["Yes","No","MayBe"];
  $scope.selectedItem = "Yes";

}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-view ng-controller="CatagoryItemsContoller">
    <div class="item item-input item-select item-margin">
        <div class="input-label">
            Pick
        </div>
        <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="o as o for o in stringArr"></select>
    </div>
</ion-view>
```

I always get an empty select box. What is happening here?

**Note: I am landing to this page via angular routing.**

Answer (score 2):

It's **ng-model** not **ng-modal**

Change

**From:**

```
<select ng-modal="selectedItem" ng-options="o as o for o in stringArr"></select>
```

**To:**

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="o as o for o in stringArr"></select>
```

Working [`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/jGOX2nCJfexddiOC9lGR?p=preview)